# How to know up comming items in list which has pagination android?

Tags: android, pagination

I have problem in pagination in Recyclerview . Here I am showing first 10 items per page, here API gives N no of items (let say 1000 items).Here every item is checked and shown if and only if item is enabled, if not.. it won't be shown.My problem is, API is giving disabled products of first 100 items, from 101'th item enabled products are being shown. So, none of items are shown in recyclerview. How can I achieve this problem?For your convenience I am showing simple API response. Your help is appreciated :)

```
{
{
"item": 1,
"status":"Disabled"
},
{
"item": 2,
"status":"Disabled"
},
{
"item": 3,
"status":"Disabled"
},
{
"item": 4,
"status":"Disabled"
},
.
.
.
.   
.
.
{
"item": 100,
"status":"Disabled"
},
{
"item": 101,
"status":"enabled"
},
{
"item": 102,
"status":"enabled"
},
{
"item": 103,
"status":"enabled"
},
{
"item": 104,
"status":"enabled"
},
{
"item": 105,
"status":"enabled"
},
{
"item": 106,
"status":"enabled"
},
{
"item": 107,
"status":"enabled"
}
.
.   
.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying "I want to show 10 items in my RecyclerView, and download 10 more when the user hits the bottom", but also "the first 10 items I download from my server are disabled, so I can't show them".

Assuming I have that right, the answer is to download items from your server until you have 10 enabled items to show, and then show those. Rather that downloading just a single chunk of 10 items, you might have to download a large number of items until you get 10 enabled ones.

Another option is to somehow change the behavior of the server so that it never returns disabled items.